# Sharepoint custom column setting

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom field in sharepoint 2007.

What I want to do is add a custom setting to it that appears not in individual items but is a property you set when you create a column.  I'd like it such that any of that column can access that property but other columns can be made of my field with their own setting.

Most of the examples/tutorials/documentation I've found seem to be either incomplete or trying to accomplish something completely different.

What functionality should I be looking at in order to accomplish this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a property to the custom field class (that's the one that inherits from `SPField`, `SPFieldLookup` or something similar); read [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/02/03/sharepoint-temporary-solution-for-getcustomproperty-and-setcustomproperty-errors.aspx) to learn how to save the value of the custom property.
2. Add appropriate UI elements to the `FieldEditorUserControl` control.

Also, check [this project](http://skypestatusfield.codeplex.com/) (source code is available).

Comment: I see the that project you linked actually uses the "PropertySchema" element in its fldtypes xml.  Can that contain a lookup?

Comment: @McAden I have no idea it can be achieved using the `PropertySchema` element. However, you can specify a custom field editor control in `FieldEditorUserControl` property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472859.aspx and such custom control can contain virtually anthing. `FieldEditorUserControl` is used in this project http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/.